# In AspNetCore/Kestrel with multiple listeners (HTTP, ConnectionHandler) on dynamic ports, which port corresponds to which listener?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, kestrel-http-server

I have a NET6 application that needs to open an HTTP service on any available port, *and* open a TCP service with a custom protocol on a different available port. The custom protocol is implemented as a [ConnectionHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.connections.connectionhandler?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

I can open the two services on available ports, and I can get the two URLs (that include the port numbers); but how can I be sure which URL/port corresponds to which service?

**Detail and code:**

Both Andrew Lock's [How to automatically choose a free port in ASP.NET Core 3.0](https://andrewlock.net/how-to-automatically-choose-a-free-port-in-asp-net-core/) and Microsoft's [Configure endpoints for the ASP.NET Core Kestrel web server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-6.0) describe how to use Port 0 to dynamically bind to an available port, and then use the IServerAddressesFeature to find the effective URL (from which the bound port can be extracted).

David Fowler provides a sample [Multi-protocol Server with ASP.NET Core and Kestrel](https://github.com/davidfowl/MultiProtocolAspNetCore) that starts Kestrel with both an HTTP service and a custom Echo handler (via `UseConnectionHandler()`).

Using this information I have created a minimal working NET6 application (below).

It seems to me that there is no way to tell which service is on which port, other than to assume that the first element in `IServerAddressesFeature.Addresses` corresponds to the first `so.Listen()`. Is there any way to be sure, in particular a method that does not depend on assumption or the undocumented behaviour of the current implementation?

```
// Minimal example of Kestrel with HTTP on dynamic port PLUS custom
// ConnectionHandler on dynamic port, and finding the port numbers.
// Connect with `curl -i %URL%`
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Features;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.WebHost.UseKestrel(so =>
{
  so.Listen(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 0));
  so.Listen(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 0),
    epo => epo.UseConnectionHandler<HttpEchoHandler>());
});

var app = builder.Build();
app.MapGet("/", () =>
{
  return "Hello, world";
});
app.Lifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(() =>
{
  // Find ports, from https://andrewlock.net/how-to-automatically-choose-a-free-port-in-asp-net-core/
  var server = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IServer>();
  var addresses = server.Features.Get<IServerAddressesFeature>().Addresses;
  Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, addresses));
  // ******** But which endpoint is HTTP and which is Echo? ********
});
app.Run();

// Adapted from https://github.com/davidfowl/BedrockFramework/blob/main/samples/ServerApplication/EchoServerApplication.cs
class HttpEchoHandler : ConnectionHandler
{
  public override async Task OnConnectedAsync(ConnectionContext connection)
  {
    Console.WriteLine($"C{connection.ConnectionId} connected");
    var header = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nConnection: close\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n";
    var headerBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(header);
    await connection.Transport.Output.WriteAsync(headerBytes);
    await connection.Transport.Input.CopyToAsync(connection.Transport.Output);
    Console.WriteLine($"C{connection.ConnectionId} disconnected");
  }
}
```

Comment: A partial solution is to use a `configure` Action to `so.Listen()` that saves a reference to the `ListenOptions` (e.g. into a Dictionary where the key identifies the service). On ApplicationStarted the ListenOptions.IPEndPoint.Port has the effective port; but this solution relies on the current behaviour of Kestrel.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have a suite of legacy GUI & CLI tools that talk to Service processes via TCP using various proprietary protocols. This suite is often deployed to small businesses with minimal IT skills; to reduce support tickets in this environment we made the Services "zero configuration" by starting them on port 0 and writing the actual port to file/registry for discovery. I am porting and merging several Services into one NET6 application, and adding an HTTP UI. It has been convenient to leverage Kestrel for this purpose, but I need to reliably find the port allocated to each protocol (to write to file)

Answer (score 0):

You have a chicken and egg problem. You can tell what ports are bound after the server starts, but you don't know which ports apply to which set of listen options. You need to do the random port generation yourself and then tell Kestrel which randomly chosen port maps to which listen options.

You can use this helper to find a free port https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/7f8cdfd502424215d978758d55e871e84c0457d8/src/Hosting/Server.IntegrationTesting/src/Common/TestPortHelper.cs#L22.

That way, you can dump the port and the type of endpoint (http or tcp protocol) to the output. The way to fix this in the future would be to have a way to query the ListenOptions in memory so you could interrogate it and prints the information.